SyncFusion: How to add additional MultiSelectComponent Field to the default editor window
I'm working on integrating a MultiSelectComponent from Syncfusion into the ScheduleComponent editor window. However, I encounter an error when clicking the input field.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enqueueForceUpdate')
    at Component.forceUpdate (react.development.js:368:16)
    at ComponentBase.renderReactTemplates (component-base.js:473:18)
    at Observer.eval (multi-select.js:281:23)
    at Observer.notify (observer.js:92:32)
    at ComponentBase.trigger (component-base.js:266:36)
    at MultiSelect.onPopupShown (multi-select.js:268:14)
    at Observer.eval (multi-select.js:5122:23)
    at Observer.notify (observer.js:92:32)
    at ComponentBase.trigger (component-base.js:266:36)
    at MultiSelect.showPopup (multi-select.js:5102:14)
    at MultiSelect.wrapperClick (multi-select.js:1099:22)

Here’s the relevant part of my component:
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import {
  ScheduleComponent,
  ViewsDirective,
  ViewDirective,
  Week,
  Month,
  Inject,
} from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule";
import { MultiSelectComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns";
import { createElement } from "@syncfusion/ej2-base";

const Calendar = () => {
  const [eventData, setEventData] = React.useState([]);

  const onPopupOpen = (args) => {
    if (args.type === "Editor") {
      if (!args.element.querySelector(".custom-field-row")) {
        let row = createElement("div", { className: "custom-field-row" });
        let formElement = args.element.querySelector(".e-schedule-form");
        formElement.firstChild.insertBefore(
          row,
          formElement.firstChild.firstChild
        );

        let container = createElement("div", {
          className: "custom-field-container",
        });
        let inputEle = createElement("input", {
          className: "e-field",
          attrs: { name: "Members" },
        });
        container.appendChild(inputEle);
        row.appendChild(container);

        new MultiSelectComponent({
          dataSource: [
            {
              id: 1,
              text: "John Doe",
              email: "john.doe@example.com",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              text: "Jane Smith",
              email: "jane.smith@example.com",
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              text: "Alice Johnson",
              email: "alice.johnson@example.com",
            },
          ],
          fields: { text: "text", value: "id" },
          placeholder: "Select Members",
          mode: "Box",
          showDropDownIcon: true,
          allowFiltering: true,
        }).appendTo(inputEle);
      }
    }
  };

  const onActionBegin = (args) => {
    if (args.requestType === "eventCreate") {
      console.log("New appointment created:", args.data);
      setEventData([...eventData, ...args.data]);
    }
    if (args.requestType === "eventChange") {
      console.log("Appointment updated:", args.data);
      setEventData(
        eventData.map((event) =>
          event.Id === args.data.Id ? args.data : event
        )
      );
    }
    if (args.requestType === "eventRemove") {
      console.log("Appointment removed:", args.data);
      setEventData(eventData.filter((event) => event.Id !== args.data[0].Id));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="mt-10">
      <ScheduleComponent
        height="800px"
        eventSettings={{
          dataSource: eventData,
          allowMultiDrag: false,
        }}
        actionBegin={onActionBegin}
        popupOpen={onPopupOpen}
        allowMultiRowSelection={false}
        allowMultiCellSelection={false}
      >
        <ViewsDirective>
          <ViewDirective option="Week" />
          <ViewDirective option="Month" />
        </ViewsDirective>
        <Inject services={[Week, Month]} />
      </ScheduleComponent>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Calendar;

What I've Tried

Ensured MultiSelectComponent initialization happens within the onPopupOpen function.
Double-checked the dependencies and their versions.
Attempted to initialize the MultiSelectComponent in different ways (e.g., using useRef).

Issue
Despite these attempts, I still get the same TypeError related to enqueueForceUpdate.
LInk to test the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/syncfusion-multi-select-issue-2-vreevz?file=index.js
Note: It looks good with simple dropdownlist component
https://stackblitz.com/edit/syncfusion-multi-select-issue-2-fdbvcc?file=index.js
Any help or insight into what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

It turned out I was importing the component wrongly.
I had to import MultiSelect instead of MultiSelectComponent

Using the MultiSelectComponent in the schedule popup open event causes the issue. Therefore, you should use MultiSelect instead of MultiSelectComponent.

Thanks for the response. As you might have already seen,  I'd already answered.
